# how to get the list of logged in employees in NetSuite using scripting

Tags: netsuite

Hi I wanted to check the list of current
currently logged in users in a our Netsuite account.

Can we do it by scripting using api's  somehow??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the login audit search, which is the closest I can get you.

https://system.netsuite.com/app/common/search/search.nl?searchtype=LoginAudit&rectype=-1

Not aware of any way to see the actual session, that's normally stored within the users PC as a cookie.

You might want to check with your network admin to see if you can make a AD script to mine those cookies or something....